# Excel formula works, but the result gives an extra number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First of all I will tell you what I have to do:

Users use a License , a lot of time, not only in business hours. Maybe one of them start using the license on friday at 14:00 , and leave the license on Monday at 10:00 , so he used the license all weekend.

What i need to find out is an excel formula, to calculate only the business hours he used it ,in this case the result would be 4 hours in friday plus 2 in monday = 6 hours. (Taking into account that the schedule is mon-fri 09:00 - 18:00

I have the following formula, which actually works, and provides "almost" the perfect result.

The issue is that in the final result , it gives the correct minutes, and in the "hour" it adds a 10.

For example, if between 1/1/2024 10:00 and 1/1/2024 11:00 , instead of having a result(in hh:mm) of 01:00 (one hour) , it says 10:00

In this example: 22/03/2023  10:56:00 / 23/03/2023  12:01:00 , the result instead of benig 01:05, it is 11:05. It is like it is adding a 1 before the main number.

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(DATEDIF(A5;B5;"D")>1;NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A5+1;B5-1;1)*10;0)/24+IF(AND(MOD(A5;1)<TIME(18;0;0);WORKDAY.INTL(A5-1;1;1)=INT(A5));(TIME(18;0;0)-MOD(A5;1));0)+IF(AND(MOD(B5;1)>TIME(8;0;0);WORKDAY.INTL(B5-1;1;1)=INT(B5));(MOD(B5;1)-TIME(8;0;0));0)
```

[image]

many thanks in advance!!

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(DATEDIF(A5;B5;"D")>1;NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A5+1;B5-1;1)*10;0)/24+IF(AND(MOD(A5;1)<TIME(18;0;0);WORKDAY.INTL(A5-1;1;1)=INT(A5));(TIME(18;0;0)-MOD(A5;1));0)+IF(AND(MOD(B5;1)>TIME(8;0;0);WORKDAY.INTL(B5-1;1;1)=INT(B5));(MOD(B5;1)-TIME(8;0;0));0)
```

Comment: Please don't add tags just because you think they might be relevant. [The `e` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e) is not applicable to your question, so I removed it. Always read the tag descriptions before you select them.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the days by 10? `NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A5+1;B5-1;1)*10`

Comment: Wouldn't it be 5 in your example? 4 on Friday, 1 on Monday since 9 to 10 is only one hour?

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed something but, why aren't you just using `=B2-A2`?

Comment: I used the "10" to specify the hours worked , (08:00 -  18:00, I wrongly typed 09:00 18:00 in the question)

Comment: yes, my examlpe is not the best, but in the first row, the result should be , in "column1", 1:05 instead of 11:05,

Comment: `11:05` instead of `1:05` is not a wrong display of a right result, it's a wrong result.

Comment: Do the start and end times always fall during business hours?

In your formula, you should take into account separately the case when the start and end dates are the same. You only consider when they differ by 1 or more (for the same dates you count as for those differing by 1).

Comment: If the answer to my question is yes, you can simply subtract `10` hours (business hours) from your result if the dates are the same.
`-10/24*(DATEDIF(A5;B5;"D")=0)`